# Working With Web Response Stream and De-serialization into C# object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, serialization

I have 2 specific questions with regards to passing a `System.IO.Stream` (from a method) and deserialization into object (another method).

XML Response I get from a `WebRequest` (please note there are no root tags)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response id="-2d953936:14174bb0cf3:-5213">
      <date>2013-10-01 12:01:55.532999</date>
      <status>
             <current>open</current>
             <next>after</next>
             <change_at>16:00:00</change_at>
      </status>
      <message>Market is open</message>
      <unixtime>1380643315</unixtime>
</response>
```

Method 1 - ResponseMethod - Currently returning string

```
private static string GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
{
      var v_Response = request.GetResponse();
      var v_DataStream = v_Response.GetResponseStream();

      var v_Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(v_DataStream);
      var x_XMLResponse = v_Reader.ReadToEnd();

       //Close all Stream logic
       v_Reader.Close(); v_DataStream.Close(); v_Response.Close();

       return x_XMLResponse;
}
```

Method 2 - Convert the XML to an object

```
// I would use XDocument and Lin2XML to get my typed object - for example MarketStatus
```

Questions are:

1. I am currently passing string from Method 1. That doesnt help me in deserializing from XML to object. Should I be passing the return value as `StreamReader` and then use that as an input into method 2 to get my typed object. Is that a standard approach or there are better ways to this?
2. My ultimate objective is that the return value from second method should be an object.

Additional Note:

1. The reason this functionality is broken into 2 methods because I want the web response method and deserailization separate for testing purposes.
2. I don't have an XSD but have created a `MarketStatus` Class

Any code snippets/suggestions will really appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We typically use a generic method, similar to the following (simplified for posting), which uses the XMLSerializer to deserialize an XML string representation into the corresponding object.

```
    public T ReturnObjectfromXml<T>(string xmlForm)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlForm);
        XmlTextReader xts = new XmlTextReader(sr);
        return ((T)xs.Deserialize(xts));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Comment: thanks for this generic class. It actually works but the problem is see my xml above - it doesnt have xmlns and hence i really cant deseriliaze it. That leaves me using LINQ2XML code here but then it no longer is generic method. Any suggestions on that? Please note I have accepted your answer since it is in the right spirit but doesnt work for me since I dont have the full formed XML

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing some type of [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing). You will be better off using WCF or ASP.NET Web API instead of rolling your own infrastructure code (to serialize and de-serialize).

To answer question 1: No, it is better to return a string and dispose of the reader as soon as you are done with it. See [When should I dispose my objects in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245856/when-should-i-dispose-my-objects-in-net)

Comment on note 1: In most cases, you wouldn't want to unit test the serialization/deserialization.